# Intellij doesn't recognize dependencies

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

i have a problem with Intellij. I have a dependency in gradle build file, when i use it in class and i will compile it with gradle it works without any problem, but intellij doesn't recognize classes in this one dependency.

```
plugins {
    id ("java")
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.8.0"
}

group = "org.hypejet.exparkour"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://jitpack.io")
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly("com.github.Minestom:Minestom:c995f9c3a9")
    compileOnly("com.github.HypeJet:HypeStom:4a6bf2a44a")
    compileOnly("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.11")
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

I tried invalidating cache, removing .idea and .gradle folders, but nothing changed. I use kotlin and gradle kotlin dsl btw.

Comment: This suggests that you should not use compileOnly: https://tomgregory.com/gradle-implementation-vs-compile-dependencies/